# Cannot set stream position with seekdir()

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

As I know, `seekdir` have to set current stream position. But if I set it - it returns the same `d_name` for any position parameter after next `readdir`. I just want to read directory name for manually entered position, and don't want to use loop with `readdir` in it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        DIR* directory = opendir(argv[1]);
        if (directory == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Enter valid directory name" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        long position = 0;
        cout << "Enter position of directory stream: ";
        cin >> position;

        seekdir(directory, position);

        dirent *dir = readdir(directory);

        cout << dir->d_name <<":"<< strlen(dir->d_name) << endl;
        closedir(directory);

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the manpage: *"The loc argument should be a value returned by a previous call to telldir(3)."*  It doesn't look like you are obtaining the argument from `telldir()`.

Comment: `telldir()` returns 0. So how I can set stream position?

Comment: Usually you use `seekdir()` to return to a point you were at before, using a value recorded from `telldir()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the POSIX standard

> The seekdir() function shall set the position of the next readdir()
>   operation on  the directory stream specified by dirp to the position
>   specified by loc. The value of  loc should have been returned from an
>   earlier call to telldir(). The new position  reverts to the one
>   associated with the directory stream when telldir() was performed.
>
> If the value of loc was not obtained from an earlier call to
>   telldir(), or if a call  to rewinddir() occurred between the call to
>   telldir() and the call to seekdir(), the  results of subsequent calls
>   to readdir() are unspecified.

In other words you can't use seekdir with a position that you get the user to enter. Only with a value returned from telldir. So you're just going to have to write that loop.

Comment: `telldir` returns current stream position. So it is useful only for different stream descriptors?

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnychuk It's useful when you want to jump back to a position you were at previously.  You can't use it to seek ahead without having obtained a value from `telldir()` previously.

Comment: It's useful if you want to save a position you have already reached and go back to it with seekdir. You are trying to use seekdir in a way that doesn't work.